# How to load an url of self certified https nodejs server inside QWebView

Tags: node.js, qt, https, openssl, qtwebview

1. Running nodejs https local server with self certified key for testing.
2. Load https://localhost:8888/index.html inside QWebView of QT Application.

QWebView shows no content.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to gokmen.

Following code ignores the ssl errors. We can use this code just for testing.

https://gist.github.com/gokmen/2558692

```
App::App(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::App)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QSslConfiguration sslCfg = QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration();
    QList ca_list = sslCfg.caCertificates();
    QList ca_new = QSslCertificate::fromData("CaCertificates");
    ca_list += ca_new;

    sslCfg.setCaCertificates(ca_list);
    sslCfg.setProtocol(QSsl::AnyProtocol);
    QSslConfiguration::setDefaultConfiguration(sslCfg);

    connect(ui->webView->page()->networkAccessManager(),
            SIGNAL(sslErrors(QNetworkReply*, const QList & )),
            this,
            SLOT(sslErrorHandler(QNetworkReply*, const QList & )));
}

void App::sslErrorHandler(QNetworkReply* qnr, const QList & errlist)
{
  #if DEBUG_ENABLED
  qDebug() ignoreSslErrors();
}
```